# Dotfuscator messes up .net cf 2.0 application

Tags: .net, compact-framework, dotfuscator

I have recently inherited a .net 2.0 compact framework application for which I have previously produced a dotfuscated release package that works and installs fine. The target OS in windows mobile 2003 and above up to 6.5.

Having made some bug fixes recently I have come to doing a new release using exaclty the same build project as for the previous one. Now I find the dotfuscated version errors with a .net framework error as follows

"The application failed to load required components.
If the .net framework is installed on a storage card, please ensure this card is in place and launch the application again. If this fails, a re-installation of the .net compact framework is recommended. Support info: -27147454964 (8000700C)"

I have no idea what could be causing this. As far as I am aware the build solution is unchanged since the last release which was fine and changes to the source code for the application consist of nothing more than refreshing a drop down list more often in certain circumstances. The application works fine if I build the installation package without using dotfuscator.

I hope someone can help with this as it's got me stumped. I have very little experience with dotfuscator which doesn't help.

thanks in advance

Comment: Mission accomplished, nobody is going to want to decompile this app.  Contact the vendor for support.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without digging into more detail. If you are still having this problem, please either contact PreEmptive support at support@preemptive.com or post a thread on the support forums at http://www.preemptive.com/forum/ where we can follow up with you directly to try to determine the cause of this problem.

--Brandon Siegel, PreEmptive Solutions

Answer (score 0):

Well I got to the bottom of this one. It was relating to signing of DLL's. I had to delay signing of the DLL's and then have dotfuscator sign them post dotfuscations with the same key file named for delayed signing.